# Android Spinner view: difference between setSelection (int position) and setSelection (int position, boolean animate)?

Tags: java, android, spinner, stack-overflow

I read the documentation, but I don't quite understand it... What is the parameter "animate" for?

Only thing I noticed:

```java
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    if (savedPosition != -1)
    {
        ((Spinner) parent).setSelection(savedPosition );
        savedPosition  = -1;
        return;
    }
   //...
}
```

...works fine with `setSelection`, but runs into endless loop / StackOverflowError with `setSelection(savedPosition, true);`

I'm really curious why this would be so?

Comment: It seems like triggering the animation will trigger the onItemSelected event, it is weird that it isn't triggered without the animation..

Comment: i'm pretty sure that it is triggered even without the animation, as I reach the //... code just after onItemSelected was called first. (Meaning, it was called twice.) Is it possible, that there is some time delay, while with animate "savedPosition" is never set to -1?

Comment: i don't know, why don't you just put "savedPosition  = -1" before setSelection()?

Comment: I did and the error actually disappeared! :-) Still a bit strange, though. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it should be doing what the name suggests. animating from the current position to the desired position. when you use just setSelection the change is more apropriate when you are trying to make sure the user sees the change (sort of a notification of a change) plus it looks smoother. at least that's why i use it. as for the animating i never had any issues with it.

why are you using the savedPosition instead of position for the selection? maybe that's what is causing the loop. my suggestion is to try to do it with position and see if it fails. your code is somewhat odd..

ye as the comment suggested you are calling the method again for some reason because i believe the animated setSelection does that when the selection is actually set.

Comment: The code looks odd because I left out quite a bit. :-)
However, I swapped the setSelection and savedPosition = -1 lines (putting savedPosition into some local variable) and it worked as well. I will keep it this way, for I can't be sure when the new "OnItemSelect" is fired. - anyway, if I want the user *not* to see the change, should I use "setSelection(int)" or "setSelection(int, false" ?

Comment: well just use setSelection(int). it is an old and stable method (less chance for some stupid fragmentation issue which anyway shouldn't happen but who knows). when both of them serve the same purpouse i would use setSelection(int).